# Database relationships and "structure"

Tags: sql, database, linq, sql-server-2008

I am not very well versed in databases but if I have this setup:

```
Payment -> Advances -> Advance Payments
```

So, a `payment` can have an `advance` resulting from a shortage in the total amount due. Per the customer, when you want to make an `advance payment` you have to 'disguise' the `advance payment` as a `payment` - for their own accounting purposes. How would I go about that.

Right now, `advances` have a foreign key to `payments` and `advance payments` have foreign keys to `advances`.

A simple scenario:

We have an order that totals $100. The customer pays $80 and $20 is advanced. So we have created an `advance` (advance 1) that is attached (fk'd) to this`payment` (payment 1). The customer orders again and the total is $50 this time and only pays $40 therefore another `advance` (advance 2) is created tied to that new `payment` (payment 2).

When the customer decides they want to pay off the `advances` a `payment` is created (payment 3) and the `advances` (advances 1 and advance 2) are added to that `payment` (payment 3). This is done so that when it gets displayed in the system the employee has the option of choosing which `advance` to make the payment to. Its not as simple as getting the total and then subtracting the `payment` amount.

So when they enter in the amount an `advance payment` is created and is attached to that `advance` because the `advance payments` are fk'd to `advances`.

**Now the question, if I want to see what advance payments were created by a payment how would i do that?**

I don't want to break my structure of `payment - advance - advance payment` - *or do I?* I thought about just having `paymentids` in the `advance payment` table but that would create a relationship between `payments` and `advance payments` that neglects the `advance` that is the middle man. I may be thinking about this incorrectly but I am not sure.

Some more info:

```
Payment Table
-------------
id : pk
amount 

Advance Table
-------------
id
amount
paymentId // payment that created the advance

Advance Payment Table
---------------------
id
amount
advanceId
```

What im proposing in which I think is wrong is:

```
Payment Table
-------------
id : pk
amount 

Advance Table
-------------
id
amount
paymentId // payment that created the advance

Advance Payment Table
---------------------
id
amount
advanceId
paymentId <---- add paymentid
```

I think this would break the structure/flow and a payment will no longer have an advance that has advance payments.

*A  little more info - we are using linq and SQL Server 2008. I don't know if that makes a difference.*

This maybe very confusing but I have tried to explain it the best way possible.

Comment: This looks like a overly complicated structure. I think you could do with `Order`s and `Payment`s only, like journal entries. At first, an order has a negative payment, the order amount. An advance is the difference between the first negative payment and subsequent payments.

Comment: the only issue is that we have to keep track of advances because a customer could have multiple advances...and could potentially pay one advance and not the other and we would need to know which advance he is paying. I think that would be a nightmare to track without a separate table

Answer (score 0):

If you have an advanceId in the AdvancePayment table then it is already linked to the Payment table. So I don't see the need for another foreign key.

So if I understood your story correct. The order price must be equal to the sum of the Payment and Advance. Then the sum of AdvancePayment amount must be equal to the linked Advance.

```
SELECT AP.id FROM AdvancePayments AP
INNER JOIN Advances A
ON AP.advanceId = A.id
INNER JOIN Payments P
ON A.paymentId = P.id
WHERE P.id = 1
```

Comment: yes we could do that however the problem is that when an advance payment is made we create a payment object and send it to the client via a webservice - that payment object has all the advance payments on it. when we submit that payment there is no correlation between the payment and advance payment

Comment: Ok you lost me. Why would there be a new payment when an advance payment is made. Because the advance payment is based on the advance being payed. And that advance is from an already existing payment.
It sounds like you want to store two different things in the same table.

Comment: thats how the client wants it for their accounting purposes we have a section in the program where all the payments for the day are calculated and totaled...and they want the advance payments which have total and amount paid and change due to show up as a payment

Comment: And it is not an option to create a view for reporting purposes that does a UNION creating the 'AdvancePayments' payments along the normal payments?